# Reduce requests to AWS Secrets Manager in lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an API on AWS using lambdas that I'm working on.

I've been looking into optimizing the amount of times I request a secret from AWS Secrets Manager using NodeJS by storing the secret outside of the `lambda` handler to avoid requesting it on every request to the lambda.

I've been able to achieve it, but I was wondering if there is a "cleaner" solution. Currently this is what I'm doing:

```js
const init = async () => {
  // Simple helper function that get's the secret based on a string name
  return await secretsHelper.getSecretValue("NAME_OF_SECRET_HERE");
};

const initPromise = init();

exports.handler = async function (event, context, callback) {
    const key = await initPromise;
    ...
}
```

Comment: What you can achieve by reducing request. Because you getting information from secrete manager which is latest one and secure one. If you pass this way then you can't guarantee if information changed in secrete manager

Comment: I see your point. However, that's not going to be an issue in this system. It will also update, just only when the container is fully down, so perhaps not instantly but eventually.

Comment: Then you can put condition secrete puller instead of `init()`